# Ant property is mutable in Windows but not Unix?

Tags: ant, properties, immutability, unset, ant-contrib

I'm working on an automated build process with Ant.

One goal is to check if a variable is already set, and if not, set it to empty string and export it as environment key to an executable. I have multiple properties files which either have the `bla` property defined or not. So I iterate through my list of files and do following:

```
<for list="${propertyfiles}" param="mypropertyfile">
    <var name="bla" unset="true" />
    <property file="@{mypropertyfile}.properties" />
    <property name="bla" value=""/>
    ... use the "bla" property for something ... 
</for>
```

To explain the lines:

```
<var name="bla" unset="true" />
```

is to make sure there is no value used from a prior loop pass. I include the property file which either has or hasn't defined the `bla` property.

```
<property file="@{mypropertyfile}.properties" />
```

to make sure that I can use the `bla` property. I thought it would be smart to use immutability of properties. So

```
<property name="bla" value=""/>
```

sets the property in case that it is not defined in my property file. In case it already is defined, the initial property value, in theory, cannot be overwritten.

Now the strange thing: on my unix system, the approach works like a charm, **on windows** it does not; **the defined property value is overwritten by the empty string**. Both machines have ant 1.8 installed.

I know that I could use `<if>` and the `<isset>` property flag to solve the issue another way but I'm just wondering how this is possible. Would be great if you could help me understanding this inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Have you verified that it's correctly loading the property file and setting the value on your Windows system? What does an `<echo>` display for the contents of `bla` before you try and set `bla` to an empty string?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with the methodology in the answer I posted? It would be nice if you could let us know what the cause was.

Answer (score 0):

Variables and unset are part of the [Variable Task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html), given you didn't mention the version of ant-contrib I have tested with both 1.0b2 and 1.0b3. While this is only a single datapoint I think you could start by assuming the truth of the result, which is that `unset="true"` on both windows and *nix in ant 1.8 allows you to reassign the value of an otherwise immutable property if it has been set previously (whether inside or out of the for loop), and has no effect otherwise.

So then between an unset call and setting your property to a default value there is a problem, which is that on windows your property is not being set as you expect it to. I would therefore look at two probable causes:

1. The property file not conforming to the [Load Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29), for example you could try running a version of unix2dos like [this program](http://www.bastet.com/) to remove any accident CRLF/LF confusion, check that you are using ISO 8859-1 character encoding (you could use something like [Text File Encoding Detector](http://www.architectshack.com/TextFileEncodingDetector.ashx) for this), and escape any unusual characters with `\"`.
2. In property files the last definition of a property wins, so you could have, for example, a linux specific in-file property expansion defaulting to `""` after your windows property.

However if `<echo> ${bla}` shows your properties are in fact being loaded correctly from the file then I would start by moving your code out of the for loop and see if it works for a single case. My test code:

```
<project name="propertyMutator" default="mutator">
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
<echo>Running ${ant.version}</echo>
<target name="mutator">
    <for list="one,two,three" param="mypropertyfile">
        <sequential>
          <var name="bla" unset="true" />
          <property file="@{mypropertyfile}.properties" />
          <echo message="Bla before default is: ${bla}"/>
          <property name="bla" value="default value"/>
          <echo message="Bla after default is: ${bla}"/>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>  
</project>
```

with

```
one.properties: bla=${some.var}
two.properties: nothing=toSee
three.properties: bla=hello1
                  bla=hello2
                  bla=hello3
```

prints

```
Buildfile: C:\workspace\proj\propertyMutator.xml
 [echo] Running Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.3 compiled on February 26 2012
mutator:
 [echo] Bla before default is: ${some.var}
 [echo] Bla after default is: ${some.var}
 [echo] Bla before default is: ${bla}
 [echo] Bla after default is: default value
 [echo] Bla before default is: hello3
 [echo] Bla after default is: hello3
```

on both linux and windows.